# Python list comprehension for dictionaries an example

Tags: python, performance, optimization, dictionary, list-comprehension

```
I have the following script:

dict_class = dict()
for p in points:
    dict_class[p.class] = dict_class.get(p.class, 0) + 1

print dict_class
{1: 1314, 2: 1050}
```

where "points" is a list of value.
My question is, is it possible to convert in a list comprehension for dictionaries in order to speed up my code?

Comment: @Bill: yet not with this loop, as that'd require self referencing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter 
from operator import attrgetter
Counter(map(attrgetter("class"),points))
```